# Unsure of solution to attribute error for module 'lightgbm' has no attribute 'LGBMRegressor' in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, anaconda3

I ran this line of code at the start of my Jupiter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import lazypredict
from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyRegressor
```

Then I received this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/c1/_3m7mbjn7pzcqcl5463xw4mr0000gn/T/ipykernel_49281/3452414230.py in <module>
      3 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      4 import lazypredict
----> 5 from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyRegressor

~/opt/anaconda3/envs/rdkit-env-test/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lazypredict/Supervised.py in <module>
     82 
     83 REGRESSORS.append(("XGBRegressor", xgboost.XGBRegressor))
---> 84 REGRESSORS.append(("LGBMRegressor", lightgbm.LGBMRegressor))
     85 # REGRESSORS.append(('CatBoostRegressor',catboost.CatBoostRegressor))
     86 

AttributeError: module 'lightgbm' has no attribute 'LGBMRegressor'
```

I have tried to look up solutions but none have worked at all. I tried to add...

```
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor, LGBMClassifier, Booster
```

after `import lazypredict` and I received another error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/c1/_3m7mbjn7pzcqcl5463xw4mr0000gn/T/ipykernel_49281/178467277.py in <module>
      4 import lazypredict
      5 import lightgbm
----> 6 from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor, LGBMClassifier, Booster
      7 from lazypredict.Supervised import LazyRegressor

ImportError: cannot import name 'LGBMRegressor' from 'lightgbm' (unknown location)
```

I also checked with `pip show lightgbm` in my Anaconda environment and this was returned...

```
Name: lightgbm
Version: 3.3.5
Summary: LightGBM Python Package
Home-page: https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: The MIT License (Microsoft)
Location: /Users/[name]/opt/anaconda3/envs/rdkit-env-test/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, wheel
Required-by: lazypredict
```

Not sure what else I can do but I will need lazy predict specifically for model comparison for a project.

Answer (score 0):

`lightgbm` v3.3.5 absolutely does have an `LGBMRegressor` class.

```bash
docker run \
    --rm \
    python:3.9 \
    /bin/bash -c "pip install lightgbm==3.3.5 && python -c 'import lightgbm; print(dir(lightgbm))'"
```

```
['Booster', 'CVBooster', 'DaskLGBMClassifier', 
'DaskLGBMRanker', 'DaskLGBMRegressor', 'Dataset', 
'LGBMClassifier', 'LGBMModel', 'LGBMRanker', 'LGBMRegressor', ...]
```

Given that `pip show` indicates that `lightgbm` is installed, I suspect that one of the following is happening:

- your filesystem has a script named `lightgbm.py` or a folder named `lightgbm/` with an `__init__.py`
- through import customization, something else has been interpreted with the name `lightgbm` (e.g. import `json as lightgbm`)

Rename any scripts named `lightgbm.py` or directories named `lightgbm/` in your working directory or any of the other directories mentioned in environment variable `PYTHONPATH`.

If that doesn't work, check for import aliasing like where something else is being imported with `as lightgbm`.